# How do I create a multi line text box in asp.net mvc?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

How do I create a multi line text box in asp.net mvc?

Probably not specific to asp.net mvc but it is what I am using.

Here is what I have.

```
<%: Html.TextBox("CommentToAdd", null, new
{
@class = "input-medium",    
TextMode = "MultiLine",
Columns = "55",
Rows = "10",
type = "text",
required = "required"
})%>
```

Answer (score 41):

just add this attribute to property.

```
  [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
   public string CommentsToAdd{ get; set; }
```

Comment: If you're answering a question, please be more specific and explain your answer, so that it will be helpful to others also.

Comment: If you are using EditorFor(), then DataType.MultilineText does the job! Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 30):

You want to use a text area, not a text box. Use [TextAreaFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703606%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to bind it to your model, otherwise use [TextArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470771%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(e => e.CommentsToAdd, 10, 55, null) %>
<%= Html.TextArea("CommentsToAdd", string.Empty, 10, 55, null) %>
```

Using razor:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(e => e.CommentsToAdd, 10, 55, null)
@Html.TextArea("CommentsToAdd", string.Empty, 10, 55, null)
```

This will be rendered as a `<textarea>` (multi-line) instead of an `<input type="text" />` (single line).

Answer (score 8):

I think multiline `textbox` in MVC is `textarea`

```
<%= Html.TextArea("Body", null, new { cols = "55", rows = "10" }) %>
```

or

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Body, 10, 55, null) %>
```

Answer (score 4):

A multiline textbox is just a textarea.

Any one of these should work.

```
<%= Html.TextArea("Body", null, new { cols = "100", rows = "5" }) %>

<%= Html.TextArea("Body", null, 5, 100, null) %>

<%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Body, 5, 100, null) %>
```